# Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-test

Ok so I have been building my flutter application , however, i can't figure you what to do in case of this error. I have been following this blog https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android , for the release build of my app .Everything worked fine , until i added

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

It gave me the following error,

```
FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.                                                        '
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources'.             
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  /Users/shuvayan/Desktop/test/srijan2020-app/build/google_sign_in/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:276:
 error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  /Users/shuvayan/Desktop/test/srijan2020-app/build/google_sign_in/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:277: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

I had the facebook_flutter_plugin and google_sign_in plugins installed for my application.
After some google search a github issue pointed me to add in the android/app/build.gradle to force use compileSDKVersion 27 even it was given 28.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

However, this didn't solve my issue and my the error's still showing up. I would appreciate a little help on this matter.

Comment: What compileSdkVersion did you set? set it to 28

Comment: @FilipP. Ya i have set the compileSdkVersion to 28 in my android/app/build.gradle from before , something else may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: fontVariationSettings  was introduced in api 28, if you set compileSdkVersion to 28 do you get same error log?

Comment: @FilipP. Ya, i have firebase plugins installed which require sdkCompileVersion to be 28, and so my build was based on 28 only!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the plugin with it's specified dependency of compileSdkVersion which have been set to Android 27

update to the most recent version of the plugin, as of now 4.2.0

References:

https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#-changelog-tab-
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/android/build.gradle

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32595