# Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources'. Flutter google sign in

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, apk, google-signin

I have created an app with flutter and firebase and i am trying to create the build apk. but i get error when running flutter build apk. i think it is because my google sign in is not setup for release.

```
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
E:\Mobile App evelopment\
Fiverr\pet_walker\build\google_sign_in\intermediates\res\merged\
release\values\values.xml:314: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
```

I have signed android apk but i have not got sha-1 production certificate for flutter. someone please guide me how to setup google sign in for production

here is the pubspec.yaml file

```
 name: pet_walker
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  provider: ^4.3.1
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.4
  after_layout: ^1.0.7+2
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
  uuid: 2.2.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  popup_menu: ^1.0.5
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1
  geolocator: ^5.3.2+2
  latlong: ^0.6.1
  carousel_slider: ^2.2.1
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  geoflutterfire: ^2.1.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: You can try this resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60796447/6942599

Comment: no that is not the issue... the issue is that i have not added release sha1 fingerprint... only debug... therefore this error is occuring...

Comment: i removed google sign in and the app built fine so it's not a problem with any sdk version